# Running in a isssue with tokenURI

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, pinata

I am running in a issue related to `tokenURI()`.
This is my function:

```
function initialize(string memory _baseUri) public initializer {
        __ERC721_init("GAME", "GM");
        __Ownable_init();
        baseUri = _baseUri;
    }

    function mint(address _address) internal {
        tokenId.increment();
        uint256 currentTokenId = tokenId.current();
        _safeMint(_address, currentTokenId);
        tokenURI(currentTokenId);
    }
```

I passed my metadata file's url which is [this](https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmaU1NBQczTWYz7cbhJDSeEugyhYPRoZrFPfcRxMkvQ79t) as `baseURI`. After deploying when i queried the value of  tokenURI it shows this: https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmaU1NBQczTWYz7cbhJDSeEugyhYPRoZrFPfcRxMkvQ79t1 for tokenId 1. When i gone to the link it shows this error:
`ipfs resolve -r /ipfs/QmaU1NBQczTWYz7cbhJDSeEugyhYPRoZrFPfcRxMkvQ79t1: invalid path "/ipfs/QmaU1NBQczTWYz7cbhJDSeEugyhYPRoZrFPfcRxMkvQ79t1": invalid CID: selected encoding not supported`.
What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because of wrong concatenation.

This is the function I use to concatenate the URI

```
    function getUri(uint256 _tokenId) internal view returns (string memory) {
    return
        string(
            abi.encodePacked(baseUri, Strings.toString(_tokenId), ".json")
        );
}
```

Check out full code here : https://github.com/Zartaj0/ERC1155/blob/c1f8ef450630b30065f876889288469d72ac539f/contracts/Joker.sol#L54

Comment: so my code is write, i will override the `tokenURI()` and edit.

Comment: But I just saw your baseURI which is a single files URI. So what is the point of concatenation in it? 
BaseURI folders look like this then you can add 1.json or 2.json or 3.json and it will direct you  to a particular file. https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmYLwrqMmzC3k4eZu7qJ4MZJ4SNYMgqbRJFLkyiPtUBZUP/

Comment: But why it is not working with 1 file? we have same code to get tokenURI, right? no matter it is a folder or single file.

Comment: Because 1 file can be a token URI of a single token. When you say base URI, it means you are defining a single URI where the Token URIs of each token exist. 

So it needs to be a folder if you are working with base URI. But if you want each token to have a different URI then you can pass empty strings to BaseURI and pass URI for every token.